# Simple bash question, -gt: unary operator expected error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Simple script.  confused by what is expected in line 2.  New to this but feeling like I'm spinning wheels trying to get pseudo code to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $a -gt 10 ]
then
  echo "Greater than 10, subtracting 1"
  let a -=1
else
  echo "Less than or equal to 10"
fi
```

Comment: have a look to https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: When `a` is empty or unset, the `[ $a -gt 10 ]` becomes `[ -gt 10 ]`, which is invalid

Comment: @OznOg shellcheck.net is big help.  Will help improve my questions.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? I think it was the semicolon you were missing on the if statement. Also, we're assuming $a is defined.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $a -gt 10 ]; then 
  echo "Greater than 10, subtracting 1" 
  let a -=1 
else 
  echo "Less than or equal to 10";
fi
```

Comment: The original newlines have been re-enabled, `then` was on its own line originally, so it wasn't this, sorry.